# add custom click event to only secondary buttons in split button list view jquery mobile

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I currently have a split button list view with `id=bookmarkslist`. Each `li` in the list is a split button list view element with a data('item') tied to each li. I would like to be able to write code that creates a click event only when the secondary button, the split view button, is pushed. I then need to be able to access the data attribute of the given `li` element (the parent of the `a` element with `class=ui-li-link-alt` who has just been clicked. I understand there are many different ways to do this, this is what I have so far:

```
$('#bookmarkslist SOMETHINGGOESHERE').live('click', function () {
    alert( $(this).data('item')['url'] );
});
```

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my way to do this:

The HTML snippet:

```
<ul id="bookmarkslist" data-role="listview">
    <li data-test="whatever1"><a href="#">test #1</a><a href="#">1.2</a></li>
    <li  data-test="whatever2"><a href="#">test #2</a><a href="#">2.2</a></li>
    <li  data-test="whatever3"><a href="#">test #3</a><a href="#">3.2</a></li>    
</ul>
```

The JQM code:

```
$("#bookmarkslist a.ui-li-link-alt").live("click", function(e){
      alert($(this).parent("li").jqmData("test")) 
});
```

This will alert the value of your the data-test attribute on the clicked LI item. Hope this helps!

Have fun...