# Add event handler on split button jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-mobile

Currently I am using the toggle() to change the split button icon to 'X' data-split-icon ="delete", but after I change the icon, I want to add an event handler to actually delete the list item. I tried this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222965/add-custom-click-event-to-only-secondary-buttons-in-split-button-list-view-jquer) for stackexchange but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Since I can't find a lot of help on this topic, is there a better way/best practice UI pattern to delete items from a list?

Here is my code so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/N7Z9e/1006/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$("#listview li .ui-li-link-alt").live("click",function(){
        $(this).parent("li").remove();
});
```

A demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/gDea8/

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, I liked the way you selected the class teaching wise. jQuery says not to use the .live() and to use the .delegate()?  So on my dev machine I made [http://jsfiddle.net/gDea8/9/](http://jsfiddle.net/gDea8/9/) but it's not working jsfiddle. Is it a okay practice to do it this way?

Comment: Whoops no it's .on() so I changed delegate to .on(). Works fine too